How to get my intended meaning using future tenses?
I want to say that I will by employed by some firm before my mum comes to visit me. Could I do this like this?

I will work in that firm by the time you arrive to see me

I will start working in that firm by the time you arrive to see me

I will be working in that firm by the time you arrive to see me


I'm sure that 2 and 3 are okay. I have doubts if 1 conveys my intended meaning.

The title of this post does not summarise the contents.  There is no way to tell what the post is about from the title "How to get my intended meaning?"

[we don't say have doubts for that kind of context.]

When we are asked what we do for a living, we can use simple present work:

I work for a large law firm as the facilities manager.

But we don't use will work with employment predictions, (i.e. declarations of mundane future intentions or plans, as in "I will be in London on the 15th", not predictions in the "seeing into the future " clairvoyant sense):

I will work for a large law firm by this time next year. unidiomatic

If we want to say that we will be employed  a large law firm by this time next year, we use the future continuous:

I'll be working for a large law firm  by this time next year.

If we want to imply that we will already be comfortably settled in the job as of a particular point in time,  we need to enlist the aid of an adverb and use the future continuous:

I will already be working for a large law firm by the time you come to visit.

If we wish to say that we will have started the new job as of a particular point in time, we use the future perfect:

I will have started working for a large law firm by the time you come to visit.


"I will work for a large law firm by this time next year" is fine if you want emphasise the "will", i.e. expressing a firm intention or prediction.

@timchessish  It is not idiomatic as prediction, but I didn't mean that in the clairvoyant sense but in the sense of normal mundane declaration about the future e.g. "I will be in London on the 15th".  I accept that it would be grammatical and idiomatic for something Madame Sosostris to predict when you line her palm with silver, and grammatical (but still not quite idiomatic)  as a statement of resolve or firm intention.   A third year law student might say it when in  Thomas-the-Tank-Engine mode.

@timchessish, the I will work … by this time next year version has a feeling of the perfective, rather like I will paint the house by this time next year. If 365 days from today I found you brush in hand and in the middle of painting your house, that would lead me to conclude that your prediction (promise? guarantee? assurance?) had been overconfident or insincere, and that in the end it was at least partly unfulfilled.

@TimR why is this unidiomatic "I will work for a large law firm by this time next year"? Let me give one more example . I train to be a good swimmer. Could I say "I will swim fast by June" or is the continuos version  needed here as well "I will be swimming fast by June"?

@marta When your meaning is that if you continue to progress at the same rate as you have been progressing, your swimming speed should be at a certain speed, once again you would use the continuous:  At this rate,  I'll be swimming the 100 meter butterfly fast enough to qualify for the national team next year.    Your suggested variant: "At this rate, I will swim... " is not really how the overwhelming majority of native speakers would phrase it.  The future continuous expresses that you will swim that fast whenever you swim in the future.

Compare:  "Your new product is selling like hotcakes.  At this rate, [you will live | you'll be living ] on Easy Street in no time!" The future continuous expresses the idea of your future ongoing mode of living, whereas the simple future will live is simply an expression of fact, like that will be your address.

@TimR often future simple is used to show something will be finished by some time like "I will fix my car by the time we drive to work" means the same as "I will have fixed my car by the time we drive to work". Can we also use future simple to show that something starts before some time and continues afterwars? Like " The trams will run by the tike we get to that city" or "I will sleep before you arrive". Fine or is the continuois tense needed here once again?

@marta "I will fix my car by the time we drive to work" is not idiomatic.  Neither is "I will sleep before you arrive".  Where are you finding these sentences?  If your car needs to be repaired by a certain day: "I will have the car fixed in time to drive to work on Thursday."  If you need some sleep before something occurs: "I will get some sleep before you arrive".

@TimR  I say "the trams will run again before we get back to the city" . Do you find it correct and with the meaning that trams will also work once we are in town or should I use a different tense?

@marta  The trams will be running again before we get back to the city.

@TimR what would my unchanged version imply to you?

@marta There's no real-world context that comes to mind.  It would imply that the speaker is a non-native speaker.

@TimR really appreciate your help. Merry chrismtas if you celebrate them.

You're right about 2 and 3 being correct and 1 being wrong, but all would convey the meaning. I don't think any native speaker would misunderstand you.
I would though correct 2 things in the rest of the sentences ...

it should be "for that firm". "in" sounds weird, in this context you would only use that for a location rather than an organisation.
"by the time you COME to see me", come implies a process, arrive implies a discrete event and really needs a time qualifier. "arrive" definitely sounds weird in this context.


why 1 would be wrong? Is it because future simple in this use with "by the time" implies completion yet "work" is atelic and that's why I'd be understood?

"Why would 1 be wrong?" Because I will work doesn't convey the idea of starting a new job.  I would suggest I will start working before you come (a single 'action') or I will be working by the time you come (a continuing situation).

@KateBunting my previous question was about trains. Could I then say "They trains will work normally before my trip" or is it unidiomatic and should be "the trains will be working normally before my trip"?

"They trains will work normally before my trip" means they will work normally at some point before my trip but says nothing about how they will be working during my trip.
"the trains will be working normally before my trip" implies that they will still be working during my trip.

Or "The trains will be working normally by the time I go on my trip".
